# SSRS: When exporting to Excel, it merges the rows into multiple

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

So I have two tables in SSRS, they are of different sizes, both are aligned to the edges (Location wise).
[Image of both tables, Left: Table A, Right: Table B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MJjD.png)

When I export the report to excel with **Table B** to the right of **Table A**, it merges the rows in excel.
[All merged except last 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RoJG.png)

When I export the report to excel with **Table B** on the bottom of **Table A**, it merges the columns in excel.
[All merged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxmq9.png)

I'm almost certain this has to do with there being 2 tables, I tried deleting **Table B** and **Table A** was perfect, also note that **Table B** needs to be to the right of **Table A**.

P.S. I'm using Report Builder 3.0 2016 version.

Comment: Do you have headers/ footers or other elements on the reports other than these items? Ive seen this happen before when there are other items on the sheet that are "creating new coloumns". It could also be that the two columns are not aligned exactly leading to white space being represented as different columns

Comment: @A.Steer, But it seems to be the rows that are the issue, how would I align them correctly like you say?

Comment: In your second screenshot (All Merged except last 3), it looks like the elements that export into Cells A to L are twice the size of the elements that export into N to P. There must be something with the design of this table that is causing the size differance. Its hard to say without the specific file, but it could be something like the CanGrow property which is forcing wordwrap or some other setting. Two tables side by side in an SSRS report is possible, a specific design element must be different on table A to be causing the issue

Comment: For the row merging, the header for the left table is larger which is offsetting all the rows below it. Set the top of both tables to be the same vertical position and then set all the rows to the same height, finally set CanGrow=False to ensure wrapping does not affect the output and it should be OK.